# Issue with Query tile widget

Tags: azure-devops

I use Query Result tiles in my dashboard to help teammates on multiple projects to quickly view the work that is assigned to them. We used to be able to click on a given task to open the detailed description of said task but now it no longer works. The tile only shows the associated user story and is no longer linking to the detailed view screen.

I have checked the queries used (simple work items and direct link query that shows all tasks assigned to a given user and its associated User Story) and reviewed the latest updates to Azure Devops but I can't find any changes that could affect the expected results.

Comment: Hi, does my answer is useful for you? Feel free to let us know the latest status.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It was indeed usefull and we have seen improvement in the last couple of days. Now the tiles do allow to click on the work item shown to access the details, but it is still stuck with a single level of work items - the hierarchy is not available as it used to. Do you know if this is still an issue or if it is still to be corrected soon?

Comment: Thank you again. Your answers have been a great help. I'll raise an issue ticket as you suggested. As of accepting your answer, I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean... is there an "Accept" tag I should be seeing? (first time user, sorry)

Comment: Aha, it's okay. You can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about this issue you meet. This is caused by our server. There are some mistake occurred on our side, so that the work item which displayed on dashboards could not be clickable successfully now.

You can follow this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/625883/azure-devops-dashboard-queries-no-longer-clickable.html) which report on Developer Community.

The fixed release has been deployed now, but haven't cover all regions. It may take some time to finish that. Please wait for this fix deploy finished. And if you still have this issue recently, you can vote and comment on Develop Community.

[image]

Our product engineers are still focusing on this issue and will help you investigate more.